# UIPageViewController is doubling up on index 1 (0->1->0->1->2->3...)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageViewController along with a UIPageControl. For some reason, the 0->1 transition on the index keeps getting called twice. For example, with this code:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.index --;

    NSLog(@")self.index --;");
    if(self.index<1){
        self.index = 1;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex: self.index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

        NSLog(@")self.index ++;");
    self.index ++;

    if(self.index==5){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex: self.index];
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    self.index = index;
    NSLog(@"index is %d", self.index);
    UIViewController *next1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    next1.view.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    next1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return next1;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 5;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return self.index;
}
```

I get this output:

```
2014-12-22 12:10:04.349 BuzzJudge[665:142581] index is 0
2014-12-22 12:10:05.030 BuzzJudge[665:142581] )self.index ++;
2014-12-22 12:10:05.031 BuzzJudge[665:142581] index is 1
2014-12-22 12:10:05.032 BuzzJudge[665:142581] )self.index --;
2014-12-22 12:10:05.032 BuzzJudge[665:142581] index is 1
2014-12-22 12:10:05.444 BuzzJudge[665:142581] )self.index ++;
2014-12-22 12:10:05.445 BuzzJudge[665:142581] index is 2
2014-12-22 12:10:05.844 BuzzJudge[665:142581] )self.index ++;
2014-12-22 12:10:05.845 BuzzJudge[665:142581] index is 3
2014-12-22 12:10:06.263 BuzzJudge[665:142581] )self.index ++;
2014-12-22 12:10:06.264 BuzzJudge[665:142581] index is 4
2014-12-22 12:10:06.627 BuzzJudge[665:142581] )self.index ++;
```

And if I slightly modify the code to permit the 0 index(what I was originally doing) it gets even worse, bouncing back between the 0 and 1 indices instead of just 0->1, like so:

```
2014-12-22 12:13:46.404 BuzzJudge[672:144489] index is 0
2014-12-22 12:13:48.147 BuzzJudge[672:144489] )self.index ++;
2014-12-22 12:13:48.148 BuzzJudge[672:144489] index is 1
2014-12-22 12:13:48.149 BuzzJudge[672:144489] )self.index --;
2014-12-22 12:13:48.150 BuzzJudge[672:144489] index is 0
2014-12-22 12:13:48.561 BuzzJudge[672:144489] )self.index ++;
2014-12-22 12:13:48.562 BuzzJudge[672:144489] index is 1
```

with this modified code:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.index --;

    NSLog(@")self.index --;");
    if(self.index<0){
        self.index = 0;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex: self.index];
}
```

I've tweaked my code trying to get rid of this, including initializing self.index to 0 or 1, and playing around with the kind of view controller I present but that's not causing it. Has anyone seen this before or know what's causing it? I couldn't find anything on SO but perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms.

Comment: I would avoid depending on the order the framework calls the methods you've overridden in your controller (i.e., don't modify the state based on the parameters or calls to the DataSource methods).

Comment: @ahruss I am not sure I understand you. Are you saying, don't change the value of self.index within DataSource methods? But if I don't, how can I keep track of the index? What I've done is what I saw in multiple tutorials. What's another way of doing this?

Comment: Of course not, you have delegate for that

Comment: @Andy I must be missing something because the code I wrote is for the delegate.

Comment: No, that code is for the DataSource, not the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that the framework is caching extra data ahead of time and your code's side effects are causing issues. You should avoid those side effects in the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods: those methods should return data, and do nothing else.

The right way to do this is some extra work, but it makes for cleaner and more maintainable code. I would make each page be a custom subclass of `UIViewController` that knows its page index, something as simple as this could suffice:

#### MyPageViewControllerPage.h

```
@interface MyPageViewControllerPage : UIViewController {
@property NSInteger index;
+(instancetype) pageWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;
}
```

#### MyPageViewControllerPage.m

```
@implementation MyPageViewControllerPage {
+(instancetype) pageWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    MyPageViewControllerPage* page = [[MyPageViewControllerPage alloc]init];
    page.index = index;
    page.view.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    page.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
}
```

Then in your DataSource implementation, update it to use this new class instead:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    MyPageViewControllerPage* page = (MyPageViewControllerPage*)viewController;
    if (page.index <= 0) return nil;
    else return [self viewControllerAtIndex: page.index - 1];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    MyPageViewControllerPage* page = (MyPageViewControllerPage*)viewController;

    // Limit to the right number of pgaes, but allow one extra at the end to signal dismissal
    if (page.index > self.numberOfPages) return nil;
    else return [self viewControllerAtIndex: page.index + 1];
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [MyPageViewControllerPage pageWithIndex: index];
}
```

This way, the UIKit framework manages everything for you. If you want to make the Page VC dismiss when you get to the last page, I would implement the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` method `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` like so:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers {
    MyPageViewControllerPage* page = (MyPageViewControllerPage*)pendingViewControllers[0];
    if (page.index == self.numberOfPages) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Make sure you set up the delegate either in interface builder or in `viewDidLoad` if you haven't already:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     // ... other initialization ...    
     self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting commentary. The only problem is that I had simplified my code for this question. In reality, I'd like to have custom view controllers which are already subclassed from custom view controllers as the pages displayed in PageViewController. So I cannot use this approach because I cannot subclass them all to MyPageViewController (since they have already been subclassed). In this case, what would you recommend as a workaround?

Comment: @SunnysideProductions I would make MyPageViewController a container for the actual VC, and add the content VC as a child of the container.

Comment: I have implemented your solution but it doesn't work. Now I am getting the index jumping from 0 to 2 in the print out. So it doesn't seem to be a problem of side effects. Thanks very much for your help. I'll message you if I figure out what it is.